# Windows batch script to search for specific files to delete

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file

I need help converting the following Linux/Mac commands into a Windows batch script.

```
find / -regex ``^.*/Excel_[a-z]*.xls'' -delete 2>/dev/null
find / -regex ``^.*/presentation[0-9]*[a-z]*.ppt'' -delete 2>/dev/null
```

Basically using regular expressions, I need to find any of the .xls/.ppt files (in the format above) in a given Windows box and delete them.

Sorry, I'm new to Windows batch files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really don't explain what your hieroglypics mean.

In a batch file,

```
@echo off
setlocal
dir /s "c:\local root\Excel_*.xls"
```

would show all of the files matching starting `Excel_` with extension `.xls`

(and if that's what you want, simply replacing `dir` with `del` would delete them; adding `>nul` would suppress messages; adding `2>nul` suppresses error messages)

If you want files starting `Excel_` then followed by any alphas-only, then

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /a-d Excel_*.xls ^| findstr /E /R "\\Excel_[a-z]*\.xls" ') do echo "%%a"
```

The `dir` produces a directory list in `/b` (basic) form (ie. filename-only) `/s` - with subdirectories (which attaches the full directory name) and the `/a-d` suppresses directorynames. This is piped to `findstr` to filter out the required filenames. The result is assigned to `%%a` line-by-line, and the `delims=` means "don't tokenise the data"

should show you all the files matching that criterion - but it would be case-sensitive; add `/i` to the `findstr` switches to make it case-insensitive. (/r means "regex" within `findstr`'s restricted implementation; /e means "ends" - I tend to use these over `$`) The `\\` in intended to implement escaped `\` to ensure the filename match is complete (ie do't find "some_prefixExcel_whatever.xls) - I'll leave what `\.` is intended to do to your imagination...

(again, change `echo` to `del` to delete and add in the redirection palaver if required)

And the other regex - well, follow the bouncing ball. It would appear you want `.ppt` files with names starting `presentation` followed by a possible series of numerics then by a series of alphabetics. I'd suggest

```
findstr /e /r "\\presentation[0-9]*[a-z]*\.ppt" for that task.
```

Comment: It did exactly what I needed! I was having trouble with the expressions in findstr. I appreciate the added method to traverse recursively into all subfolders was well. Thank you for the detailed explanation and taking the time to explain all the steps in the solution. Very knowledgeable!

Comment: There is no need for `for /f` or `findstr` or string parsing if you use PowerShell.

Answer (score 4):

Use PowerShell.

```
get-childitem | where-object { $_.Name -match '<put a regex here>' } | remove-item
```

`get-childitem` returns file system objects, and the `where-object` filter selects only those file system objects whose name property matches a regular expression. These filtered items are then passed through the pipeline to `remove-item`.

There is good information about the PowerShell pipeline in the `about_pipelines` help topic, which you can read using the following command:

```
help about_pipelines
```

Comment: That was the original idea but we ran into "digital signing issues"

Comment: There are no digital signing issues when you open a PowerShell command window and type in the above command. Scripts can easily be enabled by setting the execution policy appropriately.

Comment: Had to use a "-force Unrestricted". Thanks so much @Bill_Stewart

Comment: it's not `-force` but rather `-executionpolicy`. You can get around this by setting a sensible execution policy, which you can set in Group Policy.

Comment: The downvote is amusing. Leave shell scripts (batch files) behind and move to PowerShell. No more `for /f` ugliness.

Comment: I agree, this should not have been down voted, your answer was helpful and PowerShell was initially how I planned to do it. It was only because I was tasked to use a batch file (i know, old school) that I sought the other suggestion as an answer.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote either, as it is really a very good and appropriate answer.

Comment: Since the user is new...an explanation of *why* the answer works would be of service.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Gave you an upvote to offset the negativity because your answer seems to be right. But I'm with [OmegaMan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/285795/omegaman), I'd like to see a bit more explanation on what this command is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Plain Batch can't do this task. But you could make use of tools like findstr which come with Windows and support Regex.

This line can be executed from CMD and deletes all files in the current folder which match the RegEx:

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %F in ('findstr /r "MY_REGEX_HERE"') do del "%F"
```

So try to get your expected results by playing around with this command. If your fine with the output/results, you can embed this line in your batch script. (Be careful, when embedding this line in batchscript you have to double the percentage signs!)

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('findstr /r "MY_REGEX_HERE"') do del "%%F"
```

Comment: for /f "eol=: delims=" %F in ('findstr .*\Excel_[a-z]*.xls') do del "%F" doesn't seem to be working. Does findstr treat regular expressions in a different format?

Comment: Sorry @joeguy555 - my fault. I forgot the /r flag for RegEx. A list of supported metacharacters can be found here: http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html

Comment: I also think that since I had an unescaped regex meta-character " * " it would've caused problems? Anyways, thank you so much for your helpful and fast responses @netblognet Much appreciated!

Comment: Also note that most specialchars in bacth are escaped with the caret (^) und not with backslash (\).

Answer (score 0):

Here a small batch to do what you are looking for:

```
@echo off

set /p dirpath=Where are your files ? 
:: set dirpath=%~dp0 :: if you want to use the directory where the batch file is
set /p pattern=Which pattern do you wanna search (use regex: *.xml e.g.) : 
:: combinason /s /b for fullpath+filename, /b for filename
for /f %%A in ('dir /s /b "%dirpath%\%pattern%" ^| find /v /c ""') do set cnt=%%A
echo File count = %cnt%

call :MsgBox "Do you want to delete all %pattern% in %dirpath%? %cnt% files found"  "VBYesNo+VBQuestion" "Click yes to delete the %pattern%"
if errorlevel 7 (
    echo NO - quit the batch file
) else if errorlevel 6 (
    echo YES - delete the files
    :: set you regex, %%i in batch file, % in cmd
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b "%dirpath%\%pattern%"') do del "%%a"
)

:: avoid little window to popup 
exit /b

:: VBS code for the yesNo popup
:MsgBox prompt type title
    setlocal enableextensions
    set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%%random%%random%vbs.tmp"
    >"%tempFile%" echo(WScript.Quit msgBox("%~1",%~2,"%~3") & cscript //nologo //e:vbscript "%tempFile%"
    set "exitCode=%errorlevel%" & del "%tempFile%" >nul 2>nul
    endlocal & exit /b %exitCode%
```