# Echo only files with certain extension using DIR and FINDSTR

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, command-prompt

Just another simple question and probably duplicate of [Windows batch script to search for specific files to delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286163/windows-batch-script-to-search-for-specific-files-to-delete)

But I just can't figure it out.

In a batch file, I have the following:

`for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /s /b *.tmp ^| findstr /e /r c:"*\.tmp" ') do echo "%%a"`

In a folder on which I run the script are the files `test.tmp` and `test.tmpl`. I want the script to echo just `test.tmp`, but it doesn't echo anything. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: because of `/r`, `*`is interpreted as "zero or more of previous char". What is the previous char? You don't need `*` here. Just `findstr /e ".tmp"`. Another `/i` may be  a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but still no success.

Comment: Shouldn't `c:"*\.tmp"` be `/c:"*.tmp"`?

Comment: That was the detail I overlooked. changed `c:` to `/c:` worked :D Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because of `/r`, `*` is interpreted as "zero or more of previous char". What is the previous char? You don't need `*` here. Just `findstr /e ".tmp"`. Another `/i` may be a good idea.

```
break>test.tmp
break>test.tmpx
break>test.xtmp
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /s /b *.tmp^| findstr /ie ".tmp"') do echo "%%a"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /s /b *.tmp ^| findstr /e ".tmp" ') do echo "%%a"
```

Do not use `/R` as it uses search strings as regular expressions.